# Compare strings with different encodings

Tags: javascript, string, comparison

I've just needed to compare to strings in JavaScript, and the comparision of specific strings failed sometimes.

One value was obtained with jQuery via the `text()` method (from some auto-generated HTML):

```
var value1 = $('#somelement').text();
```

The other value is hardcoded in a JavaScript file (from me).

After some testing I found that these strings have different encodings, which became clear when I logged them with the `escape()` function.

Firebug showed me something like this:

```
console.log(escape(value1));
"blabla%A0%28blub%29"
console.log(escape(value2));
"blabla%20%28blub%29"
```

So at the end it's the whitespace with different encodings which made my comparison fails.

So my question is: how to handle this correctly? Can I just replace the whitespace to be equal? But I guess there are other control characters - like tab, return and so on - which could mess up my comparison?

Comment: No, it is not a different encoding. It only is a different whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So at the end it's the whitespace with different encodings which made my comparison fails.

No, it is not a different [encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). It is just a different whitespace - a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

> Can I just replace the white space to be equal? But I guess there are other control characters - like tab, return and so on - which could mess up my comparison?

You can replace all of them. You might want to try something like

```
value1.replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/^\s*|\s$/g, "") == value2
```

which [joins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) [multiple](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) [whitespaces](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) (of [all kinds](http://es5.github.io/#x7.2), including [returns](http://es5.github.io/#x7.3)) to a single space and also [trims](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) the string before the comparison.

Comment: Thank you very much for both clarification and the solution.