# Javascript: compare two strings with actually different encoding

Tags: javascript, encoding, string-comparison

I am comparing two presumably differently encoded file names, in Javascript, with the hope to find matches:

- One file name is **an actual file name**, from within a unarchived zip (using https://stuk.github.io/jszip/)
- One file name is a **name extracted from a bplist** (iOS archive format unarchived with https://github.com/joeferner/node-bplist-parser)

## Analysis

When comparing the log output in the javascript console, these file names look exactly identical:

```
15 - Beschänkt und gsägnet - PLAYBACKVERSION.mp3
15 - Beschänkt und gsägnet - PLAYBACKVERSION.mp3
```

Note the german umlauts.

Now, when I just copy and paste these strings into Notepad++ and enable the hex editor, it looks like this:

[image: The above text in hex]

- In the first case the **A-Umlaut is encoded with 3 (three)** bytes
- In the second case the **A-Umlaut is encoded with only 2 (two) bytes.**

## Question

How can I safely compare those two strings. **Is there a general "unencode" method in Javascript that can handle these instances?** Or should I / must I guess each encoding and then compare explicitly?

## Note

- I am specifically asking for a solution in javascript
- This question, [Compare strings with different encodings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738787/compare-strings-with-different-encodings) althoug similar is not actually about encoding

Answer (score 4):

## What's happening here?

If you have a `String` in JavaScript, it's a sequence of Unicode codepoints. Some component has already decoded the bytes representing those strings from the ZIP or the plist into a sequence of codepoints.

That is, this question is not quite about encodings, but about Unicode decomposition and normalization forms.

It's possible to encode an ä in (at least) two different ways in Unicode (examples below in Python due to the useful outputs).

```
>>> "ä".encode("UTF-8")
b'\xc3\xa4'  # two bytes
>>> [ord(c) for c in "ä"]
[228]
>>> [unicodedata.name(c) for c in "ä"]
['LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS']
```

or in the NFKD normalization form, taking two codepoints and three bytes in UTF-8.

```
>>> unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", "ä").encode("UTF-8")
b'a\xcc\x88'  # three bytes
>>> [ord(c) for c in unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", "ä")]
[97, 776]  # two codepoints
>>> [unicodedata.name(c) for c in unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", "ä")]
['LATIN SMALL LETTER A', 'COMBINING DIAERESIS']
```

## Answer

Long story short, in JavaScript, you'll need to call [`String#normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) to make sure the strings are in the same normalization form before attempting regular comparison.

```
$ node
Welcome to Node.js v16.6.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
> var a = '15 - Beschänkt und gsägnet - PLAYBACKVERSION.mp3';
undefined
> var b = '15 - Beschänkt und gsägnet - PLAYBACKVERSION.mp3';
undefined
> a.length
50
> b.length
48
> a === b
false
> a.normalize() === b.normalize()
true
>
```

Comment: "I am specifically asking for a solution in javascript" - OP.

Comment: @Rojo Yep. That's what the link in the end is. Examples are in Python because it has useful visualizations for the different normalization forms.

Comment: The weird thing is that JavaScript strings are UTF-16, and lower-case "a" with diaresis in JavaScript is 0x00E4, one UTF-16 codepoint.

Comment: @Pointy UTF-16 is the internal memory representation JavaScript uses, that doesn't factor in here (since we're not talking about codepoints >= 0xFFFF). 0xE4 is 228 in decimal, the same codepoint in the Python illustration.

Comment: Right but what I'm confused about is how the OP is ending with something *other* than a simple 00E4 codepoint for the "a" diaresis characters. Maybe the text is UTF-8 in the source files, and different UTF-8 as you say, but some code has to build JavaScript strings from those somehow.

Comment: Because the binary data had been decomposed to begin with is my guess. Since OP is talking about Apple plists, I'd wager the ZIP has been created on a Mac too, and Mac file systems store filenames in [NFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus#Design). You can emulate this with `String.fromCodePoint(97) + String.fromCodePoint(776)`.

Comment: @AKX You are right with your guess. Both the plist as well as the ZIP file were created on an Apple device (but extracted and compared with Javascript on a Windows box)